# Acquire the last three digits of an Int

Tags: java, integer, int, substring

I'm trying to get the last three digits of a int which value can be anything over 999 in a string or int format.

For example if I received the int 12345678 I would get the value 678.

Currently I can only satisfy this for int's which are 4 digits long such as 1899.

Using
  String.valueOf(numberReceived).substring(1);

Comment: Get the remainder of that number divided by 100: `numberReceived % 1000`

Comment: Suppose your string has 5 characters, what should you pass to substring? And if it's 6 characters? And 7? Don't you see a quite simple relation between the number of characters, and the value to pass to substring? Something related to the number 3? It's basic arithmetics, nothing fancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the number of digits in numberReceived and get the last 3 digits by using the substring method:

```
String.valueOf(numberReceived).substring(String.valueOf(numberReceived).length()-3);
```

Answer (score 1):

The modulo (`%`) operator, lets you obtain the remainder after a division. In your case, you want the last three digits, so you'll need to use  `% 1000` to obtain the correct remainder.

For example, `2500 / 1000 = 2`. The remainder is 500. `2500 % 1000 = 500`

```
public static int lastThreeDigits(int i) {
    return i % 1000;
}
```

It's important to note that the resulting `int` will not necessarily have three digits. E.g. `2039` will give you `39` rather than `039`.

To ensure you have three digits, you'd need to convert the result to a String. E.g. `String.format("%03d", i)`

If your original number is in a `String` format and you want to get the last 3 characters, you could use string manipulation instead of arithmetic. For example here is a more generic function to obtain a number of characters from the end of a string:

```
public static String lastNChars(int n, String s) {
    return s.substring(Math.max(0, s.length() - n));
}
```

There are loads of different ways to write it depending on what you want.